# Source tag didn't update the src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I tried to use **useState** to update the video background, but it seems not working.

Here is my code:

```
  const [bgChange, setbgChange] = useState(backgroundDay);

  const handleBackground = () => {
    bgChange === backgroundDay
      ? setbgChange(backgroundNight)
      : setbgChange(backgroundDay);
    console.log(bgChange);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="-z-50 absolute">
        <video className="videoTag" autoPlay loop muted>
          <source src={bgChange} type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleBackground}>Change BG</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: the updated value of `bgChange` will be available in the next render, so move your `console.log` outsede of `handleBackground` and check the result.

Comment: the background doesn't change anything @@

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't change anything"? What is it that currently happens and what is it that you want it to do?

Comment: This looks like it may be a problem with the values stored in `backgroundNight` and/or `backgroundDay`

Comment: I mean the src atribute didn't update, thus the background didn't change when I click to the Change BG button

Comment: `import backgroundDay from "../assets/backgrounds/BG-Day.mp4";
import backgroundNight from "../assets/backgrounds/BG-Night.mp4";`

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
bgChange === backgroundDay
      ? setbgChange(backgroundNight)
      : setbgChange(backgroundDay);
```

to

```
setbgChange(
    bgChange === backgroundDay 
    ? backgroundNight 
    : backgroundDay
);
```